# Creating variable with String to pass as uchar*

Tags: c, types

I am writing a program that passes text to a library function.
This function expects the text parameter to be of type *unsigned char**.

So how can I properly pass a String to that function? I fail at converting an existing *char** to *unsigned char** and writing a new value into an *unsigned char** variable via *strncpy* also didn't work.

Edit:
Here is a small example:

That is the function I need to call:

`int count (void *index, uchar *pattern, uint length, uint *numocc);`

This is what I have in my code:

```
count(index,?argv[2]?, length, numocc);
```

Comment: Please provide an minimal example that illustrates the problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do typecasting with `(unsigned char*)`. I am posting a small example may be it help you(*read comments*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void func(unsigned char* str){ // argument should be unsigned char*
    printf("\n In side fun:  %s\n", str);
}
int main(){
    char* s = "your_name"; // s is char* 
    func((unsigned char*)s);  // notice type casting
    return 1;
}
```

and it works:

```
~$ gcc x.c  -Wall
~$ ./a.out 

 In side fun:  your_name
~$
```

**EDIT**:

```
count(index, (uchar*)argv[2], length, numocc);  
               ^ typecast (uchar*)
```

`uchar*` may be a typedef ed  in your code like:

```
typedef unsigned char* uchar*
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought just casting this woldn't really change the internal representation but actually it did.